# How to pipe to Set-ADComputer

Tags: powershell, csv

How do you pipe information into a `Get-ADcomputer` command in PowerShell?

I'd like to import a list of computers and descriptions from a CSV file and use the CSV data to gather additional information for the computers listed in the CSV file. However, when I attempt to use information from the CSV file, the `Get-Command` runs using the string (`$_.description`) instead of the description info from CSV file (value of `$_.description`).

My code:

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Temp\computers.csv -Header @("name","info","description")
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    Get-AdComputer -LDAPFilter "(description = $_.description)" -Properties * -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase "OU=computers,DC=example" 
}
```

Comment: What are the headings in your csv?

Comment: `foreach` is one word. And since you are using `foreach` and not `ForEach-Object` with a pipeline, you will use the defined variable. e.g. `_.description` -> `$line.description` (Also $computer would be more descriptive than $line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (I am assuming one of your headings in the csv is name description):

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Temp\computers.csv
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    $description = $line.description
    Get-AdComputer -LDAPFilter "(description = $description)" -Properties * -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase "OU=computers,DC=example" 
}
```

Comment: I experience the same issue with $line.description. Instead of the value of $line.description what actually executes is the string $line.description.

Comment: `$_` not being populated by a `foreach` loop is only one half of the problem. The other half is that property expansion inside a string doesn't work.

Comment: THANK YOU @AnsgarWiechers!  Property expansion inside a string was the issue. Created a variable for the description and that resolved it.